# Can't debug WCF (x86) after Win8.1 upgrade

Tags: wcf, windows-8.1

I have a WCF app which has to run in x86 mode due to some legacy dll's it calls. Everything worked fine on Windows 8 but now that I've upgraded to 8.1 it fails (no changes have been made to my code). When the wcf hosting app in Visual Studio starts it fails to host the service but if I select 'Any CPU' to works (but my app fails due to the legacy dll's). It appears as though the wcf hosting app doesn't support the x86 mode anymore/correctly.
I put a question about this on the MSDN WCF forum and was told to add it to the Win8.1 forum, I did that and was told to put it on the MSDN WCF forum. So now I'm asking the question here hoping that I will finally get an answer or at least find out if anyone else is also experiencing this problem.
SteveR

Comment: I think, I've got the same problem: Do you get any exceptions or messages? When I try to start a service, either in WCFTestClient or in my application, nothing happens. WCFTestClient's progress bar stops at 50% and remains like this. Debugging my own software, the construction of the client (... = new XYServiceClient();) works. When performing an operation on the service, nothing happens the program is stuck in the calling line.. Same for you?